# Not able to parse Json DeserializingObject class

Tags: json, json.net

I have tried many permutations but no luck. My data:

```
{
"100": 
{
    "SI": {
        "conversionFactor": 0,
        "conversionOffset": 0,
        "format": "",
        "suffix": ""
    },
    "US": {
        "conversionFactor": 0,
        "conversionOffset": 0,
        "format": "",
        "suffix": ""
    },
    "datax": 1879,
    "dataY": 1,
    "description": "Some datam",
    "siZ": {
        "conversionFactor": 0,
        "conversionOffset": 0,
        "format": "",
        "suffix": ""
    },
    "values": []
},
"ZZ_yes": ...same reapeat but different values
```

I use classes to parse the data:

class Search_Fge1_results
    {

```
    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "")]
    public string DataItemName { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dataitem")]
    public dataitem DataItem{ get; set; }

}
```

class dataitem
    {
        public string ditem { get; set; }

```
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "S1")]
    public abbs1 S1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "US")]
    public abbus1 US { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "datax")] // Ei luokka vaan avainpari
    public string Datax { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dataY")] // Ei luokka vaan avainpari
    public string DataY { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")] // Ei luokka vaan avainpari
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "siZ")]
    public abbus1 Siz { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "values")]
    public string[] Values { get; set; }


}
```

My code:
..

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Search_Fge1_results>(result);
```

It return error or null value .. what is wrong?

Comment: Post your JSON in full please like you posted the classes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go to someplace like here:
http://json2csharp.com/

You can paste in the JSON sample, and it will output a list of C# objects that match the sample.

You can also [create objects from JSON samples within more recent versions of Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc/).

Be aware that a JSON sample can be minimized to just the data it requires.  So a JSON response string coming from the same source later could have additional properties.  It would be best to start here to see what the code should roughly look like, and then look at the specification for the service, following the patterns illustrated by the generated code, and add the additional properties you need.

Off the bat, I see issues with your property naming (**SI** vs. **S1**) and you've not provided what `abbus1` and `abbs1` look like (if they are supposed to be different).  But if you generate the code using one of the services above, you'll likely see those issues corrected.